# Which modules are missed?

Tags: perl, cpan

On my system:

```
$ uname -ra
Linux web.feel-safe.net 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I get next errors while installing modules:

```
Can't locate inc/ExtUtils/MY_Metafile.pm in @INC (you may need to install the inc::ExtUtils::MY_Metafile module) (@INC contains: /home/feelsafe/web/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/feelsafe/web/local/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at Makefile.PL line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 4.
```

.

```
Configuring List-MoreUtils-0.416
Running Makefile.PL
Can't locate inc/latest.pm in @INC (you may need to install the inc::latest module) (@INC contains: /home/feelsafe/web/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/feelsafe/web
/local/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/per
l/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at Makefile.PL line 51.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 51.
```

.

```
Configuring MRO-Compat-0.12
Running Makefile.PL
Can't locate inc/Module/Install.pm in @INC (you may need to install the inc::Module::Install module) (@INC contains: /home/feelsafe/web/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/feelsafe/web/local/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at Makefile.PL line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 1.
-> N/A
-> FAIL Configure failed for MRO-Compat-0.12. See /home/feelsafe/.cpanm/work/1524673518.17946/build.log for details.
```

Currently I have found [this](https://perlmaven.com/cant-locate-inc-module-install-in-inc) article, but still do not understand the problem.

What did I miss on my system? And what is the problem?

Comment: The Perl install on this system is crippled. Try building your `perl`, and using that to install whatever modules you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I use `Carton` to deploy my application:

```
carton install --deployment
```

I have `List-MoreUtils-0.416` in my `cpanfile.snapshot`. Thus I use old module version which relies on "." exists at `@INC`.

But on target host, where I was faced into `Can't locate inc/latest.pm in @INC` problem there is **DEBIAN** `perl-5.24.1` which apply patch from `perl-5.26` which removes '.' from `@INC`

Because of this `inc::latest` is not found in bundled directory

To resolve my issue I just add next line into `cpanfile`:

```
requires 'List::MoreUtils', '>=0.428'
```

Unfortunately `carton update` do not update all modules from `cpanfile.snapshot` just only mentioned at `cpanfile`.

Also, I think, it will be OK to install `inc::latest`

Answer (score 0):

You may be using the "system" perl (*cf*. [`perlbrew`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::perlbrew)) where the library paths in `%INC` assume modules are installed using the operating system's package manager.

When building modules it's sometimes easier to use a locally built `perl`, a module "bootstrapping" utility like [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib), or [`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl) to manage your "non-system" instance of `perl`. This allows you to easily avoid mixing module packages installed by the OS with your own locally built modules.